# Airflow - Chart Query failing

Tags: airflow

I am new to Airflow and I am trying to create charts for my DAG but I keep getting the following error:

```
SQL execution failed. Details: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_pandas_df'
```

My query looks like:

```
SELECT dag_id, execution_date, count(*) as ccount FROM task_instance GROUP BY dag_id, execution_date
```

Comment: If you run your query directly on the DB does it return something? Also put more details on what you are doing/trying.

Answer (score 6):

In the web UI, if you click on the pen-shape edit button, you'll see the connection (Conn Id field) it uses is `airflow_db`, which means you need to make sure the `aireflow_db` connection (in the top menu `Admin` -> `Connections`) is configured to point to the database you set in the airflow.cfg file.

Comment: Is there a way to make this automatically point to the db in airflow.cfg? Seems redundant to have to change it twice.

Comment: @NightFantom don't that i'm aware of, maybe try raise an issue to them?